# Google play keeps warning missing intent type of ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-console, android-tv

I published an app for Android TV, but the Play Console keep rejecting the app update with the reason:

Your app manifest does not set an intent type of ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER.

I'm sure that there is a main activity in my Manifest like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="my.android_tv.AndroidTvHomeActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_banner"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name_short"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher_banner"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myUI.LeanbackBrowse">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also I requires some features like this:

```
<uses-feature
    glEsVersion="0x20000" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false"/>
```

There is no special permission required.

```
<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


<uses-permission
    name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission
    name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

<uses-permission
    name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission
    name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I did appeal and receive this feedback from Google:

> "For example, the app displays "android.software.leanback" but is
> displaying "Has Leanback Intent: false" for the DFX Properties list."

Anyone can show me where the mistake is? I don't know what DFX Properties list is, because there is no information about it.

Comment: You don't need to add "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" category, only LEANBACK_LAUNCHER. Maybe it's the culprit.